# how to add an id's of one collection to arrays of id of other collection using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have 2 collections one is 
Products which looks like the following

```
  var ProductSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    id:[parts_id],    // What should i change here to embed all the id's of parts collection in array 
   });

  var partSchema =new Schema(
    {
    "_id":autogenrated id",
    "price" : number,
    "properties" : {
    "battery type" : string,
    "talktime" : string,
    "weight" : number
    },
 });

 var Product = mongoose.model("Product");
 var product = new Product(

{
    "_id":"auto generated Id",
    "name" : "iphone 5",

 } 

 and other is parts which look like this 

 var parts = mongoose.model("parts");
 var parts = new parts(
 {
    "_id":autogenrated id",
    "price" : "$650",
    "properties" : {
    "battery type" : "lithium",
    "talktime" : "8 hours",
    "weight" : 2.3
  },
});
```

and these two collections have one to many relationship, many being the parts collection. I want to add the id's of parts collection into an array of products collection for referencing. How can I do that using mongoose and what is the syntax for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
var ProductSchema = new Schema({
   name: String,
   parts:[{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'parts' }]],    
});
```

By the way, I think you need to include the schema when declaring the model:

```
var parts  = mongoose.model('parts', partSchema);
var Product = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

Also, you should consider a consistent naming convention regarding casing and singular/plural forms of the names.

Since it looks like you are attempting a relational model with `Mongoose`, I'm including the documentation regarding [.populate()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I haven't tried that and yeah I had one more doubt can we use
 
   parts:[{type:parts.Types.ObjectId}] where parts is the name of the schema

Comment: @Yash `Schema` is an object from the `mongoose` library. 

`var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;`

Comment: ohh I see!! okie lastly Just wanted to ask you when you add a new document to parts collection how does the Id of the newly created parts get added in an array of products? What is the syntax for that?

Comment: @Yash just push the _id of the part into the parts [] in the product document before saving.